# char casting on integers above 255

Tags: c#, casting, char

Just a quick one- why does c# allow char casting of ints above 255?

e.g.

```
Console.Write((char)300);
```

it shouldn't return characters but it does (even for big ints) so how does it determine these characters? does it auto translate to different character formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a [char in .NET is a Unicode-Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx), i.e. it is 16 bit long.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being 16 bit long you could do this:

```
unchecked
{
   char c = (char) 70000;

   MessageBox.Show(((int)c).ToString());
}
```

It gives (70000 % 65536). 66536 is the max of a 16 bit number.